# Package Manager Console not opening

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, package-manager-console

When ever i try to open package manage console from my visual studio 2017(Community) it will give me following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)

Comment: Close your Vs and delete all temp files from your PC then restart it should work if not then update your VS.

Comment: Nope, its not working.. :(